# Porting NewLib for my OS: some questions

Tags: c, gcc, ld, newlib

I am trying to port NewLib for my OS (I am following this tutorial:   http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib), and I have some questions.

- Once LibGloss is done and compiled, when exactly will I have to use the libnosys.a that have been created? Is it when I will compile my main.c?

  ```
  mipsel-uknown-elf-gcc main.c -Llibnosys.a`
  ```
- My crt0.c is done. And I have to "link it as the first object". How can I do that? Is it something like this?

  ```
  mipsel-uknown-elf-ld crt0.o main.o
  ```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Linking as the first object might work just fine like you are displaying, but the docs does mention using a linker script and adding crt0.o as STARTUP() -- I'm not too familiar with linker scripts, but you can find the default linker script and possibly create it/adjust it:

Syntax of linking script: http://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts

```
The linker always uses a linker script. If you do not supply one yourself, the linker
will use a default script that is compiled into the linker executable. You can use the 
`--verbose' command line option to display the default linker script. Certain command
line options, such as `-r' or `-N', will affect the default linker script.
```

The same can probably be done with other system libraries that always have to be part of the linking.

It's fine to add all on the command line, but a bit tedious in the end.

Are you getting any errors or wrong results since you are asking or what?